# Trying to print the Nested Json

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

```
var key = " ";
var myBio = {
              "name":"Sathya",
               "age":"23",
            "position":"Soft.Engineer",
             "email":
                     {
                       "email1":"sathya@gmail.com",
                        "email2":"sathya@knstek.com"},
                     };

for (key in myBio){
   var y = myBio[key]; 
   console.log(key+" : "+ y);   
        }
```

**output:**

- name : Sathya
- age : 23
- position : Soft.Engineer
- email : [object Object]

**Required Output:**

- name : Sathya
- age : 23
- position : Soft.Engineer
- email :

  - email1:sathya@gmail.com
  - email2:sathya@knstek.com

I can print this Emails separately using another loop. But I want to print with main loop only . Any ways to do this using JavaScript??

Comment: It's because you try to concatentate object to string. You don't have to do that. Solution is to use `console.log(key, y)`

Comment: did you try simple console.log(myBio)?

Answer (score 3):

Most people searching in Google and finding this question are probably looking for something like this:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(object, null, 2));
```

This prints deeply nested JSON to the console without the annoying "[Object]".

The last two parameters are optional. The 2 says to pretty print the JSON with an indent of 2. If left blank, will output non-formatted JSON.

This does not answer this specific question, but hopefully will answer those searching for "Print nested JSON Javascript".

Answer (score 1):

```
function recursion(myBio) {
  for (var key in myBio) {
    if (typeof(myBio[key]) == 'object') {
      recursion(myBio[key]);
    } else {
      alert("Key: " + key + " Values: " + myBio[key]);
    }
  }
}
```

use this subroutine if you have nested json

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) function to get this done.. example

```
function logRecursive(object){
  for (key in object){
  var value=object[key];
  if(typeof value === 'object'){
     console.log('{');
     logRecursive(value)
     console.log('}');
  }else{
    console.log(value);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var myBio = {
    "name" : "Sathya",
    "age" : "23",
    "position" : "Soft.Engineer",
    "email" : {
        "email1" : "sathya@gmail.com",
        "email2" : "sathya@knstek.com"
    },
};

function print(bio) {
  for (var key in bio) {
    if (typeof(bio[key]) == 'object') {
      print(bio[key]);
    } else {
      console.log(key + ": " + bio[key]);
    }
  }
}

print(myBio);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```js
var myBio = {
    "name":"Sathya",
    "age":"23",
    "position":"Soft.Engineer",
    "email": {
        "email1":"sathya@gmail.com",
        "email2":"sathya@knstek.com"
    }
};

var result = parseJSON(myBio);

console.log(result);

function parseJSON(obj) {
    var parsedData = '';
    for(var i in obj) {
        if (typeof obj[i] == 'object') {
            parsedData += parseJSON(obj[i]);
        }else {
            parsedData += i +' : '+ obj[i];
        }//end if
        parsedData += '\n';
    }//end for
    return parsedData;
}//end function
```