# NextJS: TypeError: Cannot read property 'json' of undefined

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, next.js

I've this code into pages folder on my NextJS environment. It gets data calling an external API Rest, and it's working because the `console.log(response);` line show me by console the Json API response. The problem I've is that I get this error in browser:

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'json' of undefined**

Corresponding with this line code:

`const data = await res.json();`

This is the complete file with the code:

```
import React from "react";
import fetch from "node-fetch";

const getFetch = async (invoicesUrl, params) => {
  fetch(invoicesUrl, params)
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};

export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
  const invoicesUrl = "https://192.168.1.38/accounts/123456";
  const params = {
    method: "get",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  };
  const res = await getFetch(invoicesUrl, params);
  const data = await res.json();
  console.log("Data Json: ", data);

  return { props: { data } };
};
```

This is the Json API response that I see by console:

```
{
  account: [
    {
      id: '7051321',
      type: 'probe',
      status: 'open',
      newAccount: [Object],
      lastDate: '2020-07-04',
      taxExcluded: [Object],
      totalRecover: [Object],
      documentLinks: []
    },
  ]
}
```

Any idea how can I solve it?
Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**
Here the code working good:

```
import React from "react";
import fetch from "node-fetch";

const getFetch = async (invoicesUrl, params) => {
   return fetch(invoicesUrl, params);
};

export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
  const invoicesUrl = "https://192.168.1.38/accounts/123456";
  const params = {
    method: "get",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  };
  try {
    const res = await getFetch(invoicesUrl, params);
    const data = await res.json();
    console.log("Data JSON: ", data);
    return { props: { data } };
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Data ERROR: ", error);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things you have to change.

```js
const getFetch = async (invoicesUrl, params) => {
  fetch(invoicesUrl, params)
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
      return response; // 1. Add this line. You need to return the response.
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};

export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
  const invoicesUrl = "https://192.168.1.38/accounts/123456";
  const params = {
    method: "get",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  };
  const data = await getFetch(invoicesUrl, params);
  // const data = await res.json(); 2. Remove this you have already converted to JSON by calling .json in getFetch
  console.log("Data Json: ", data); // Make sure this prints the data.

  return { props: { data } };
};
```

Comment: I've made that changes you suggest, and now I get this error: "SerializableError: Error serializing `.data` returned from `getServerSideProps` in "/invoicing/invoices".
Reason: `undefined` cannot be serialized as JSON. Please use `null` or omit this value all together". There are two "return" into your getFetch function, is that correct?

Comment: The reason is that the response returned from your API is not serializable. If you update your question with the full object I will be able to point where the problem is. If not, you can find it out yourself using the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30579940/reliable-way-to-check-if-objects-is-serializable-in-javascript

Comment: Ok, probably the reason to not be serializable is those elements with content "[Object]" in the console but with content if I call the API with another way (curl, Postman).

Comment: Yes, it is something inside [Object] that is not serializable. For NextJS, it needs to be serializable. You can use this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41587443/trying-to-print-the-nested-json to print the entire structure and see where the problem is.  I'll be happy to help more.  Btw I think I have fixed the original issue for the question. If so please accept..:)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll take a look to that link. Sorry, but I can't accept your answer as correct (i don't want confuse another users) because it can't work for me after try many times. I've updated my original question and after UPDATE title I putted the code that works for me. However, may be another user with this issue can vote your answer as the right! Thanks again.

Comment: No problem.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You have return statement in wrong place.
When the function is expecting a return. You need to return when the statements are executed not inside the promise `then` function because it is an async callback function which is not sync with the statement inside `getFetch`function. I hope i have made things clear. Below is the code which will any how return something

```
import React from "react";
import fetch from "node-fetch";

const getFetch = async (invoicesUrl, params) => {
  return fetch(invoicesUrl, params);
};

export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
  const invoicesUrl = "https://192.168.1.38/accounts/123456";
  const params = {
    method: "get",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  };
  try{
     const res = await getFetch(invoicesUrl, params);
     console.log("Data Json: ", res);
  }catch(error){
     console.log("Data Json: ", error);
  }
  return { props: { res } };
};
```

Comment: Ok, thanks! it helped me. Now my code is working. I will update my original question with the code working. However, here I thing you should change "return { props: { data } }" by "return { props: { res } }". Thanks again.